# ASP.NET: What do I do, when the customError page gives an error?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have the following customErrors section in my ASP.NET application:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
   <error statusCode="500" redirect="500.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

How do I show user-friendly message, if "500.aspx" gives an error (it could happen when the database is down, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static page (e.g. 500.html) to avoid this problem.

In response co comment:

> I would like to use static page ONLY when "500.aspx" doesn't work.

The only sure way to know if 500.aspx is going to work is to try it.  So in this case, you could define 500.aspx in the `customErrors` element of web.config, and handle the specific case of 500.aspx in global.asax, e.g. :

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpException httpException = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
    if (httpException == null) return;
    int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
    if (httpCode == 500 && 
        Request.Path.EndsWith("/500.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect("~/500.htm");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to use the "500.aspx" whenever possible. Because it keeps all website information stored in the database: navigation, company email, logo, etc. Can I use static page in case of the "500.aspx" gives an error?

Comment: To clarify: I would like to use static page ONLY when "500.aspx" doesn't work. Otherwise "500.aspx" is used. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you create one errorpage and always let the user end up there. Or do you want each statusCode a specific page?
You can even add a mail-method to inform you about certain errors if you like.

Comment: I would like to use a separate page per error code. That's what our client get used to do in the CMS. So how do I enable email notifications without messing around with C#?

Comment: The mailmethod is via c#, so if you don't want to make use of that I doubt if you can do that.

Comment: ah, ok. just thought there's specific setting for that in the web.config.